# google-services.json cannot be found

Tags: android, flutter

I have put the google service json file at `android/app/src`
buh I get this error:

```
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/profile, src/profile/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/profile, src/nullnullProfile]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
}
```

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#5 this says the file should be in `android/app` not `android/app/src`

Answer (score 3):

Place **google-services.json** in the `android/app` directory instead of `android/app/src`.

Comment: tried that but it now giving me the error
``
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
null value in entry: incrementalFolder=null

``

Comment: That should be a different issue. Do you only get that message?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

at application gradle you should add

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'.
```

you should add below dependency

```
dependencies {
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

**google-services.json** file you can download from **google console** and put at app location

- switch to Project view so you can see the actual **project folder structure.**
- find **google-service.json file** and drag it to the **app directory** (for some reason when I added it using file explorer, it put it in the gradle folder).
- Clean/Rebuild project.

it works for me

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issue. I tried this and it's working fine for m.
I think this works for cordova and ionic apps.

https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/219#issuecomment-282312015